# Why does DAC INL follow a pattern, with peaks repeating at certain specific intervals?

Tags: analog, dac

INL curves seem to have relation with "digital" effects from the codes,like a major carry transition. Could someone help me understand an electrical or rather an analog, explanation for this occurance.

Would this be the case with DACs implemented as simple R-Strings, that donot have binary weighted elements in their architecture ?  Here is a crude drawing to explain the INL pattern that I have been trying to explain.[image]

Answer (score 0):

DACs are (usually) implemented with R-2R resistor ladders, whose linearity depends on the resistor ratios staying correct.  If the resistors don't match, you'll get effects like that.

Comment: I worked with a guy who designed a 100MHz 14-bit DAC, 20 years ago, for cellphone basestation signal synthesis. He used 17 DACs, with 1 of the 17 always being calibrated. That moved the INL to faster periods than the 16 segments (the 4 MSBs).

Comment: @analogsystemsrf: wow.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am more interested in knowing what a INL trace like this has to tell about the layout or the process. I wonder if there is a correlation between design/layout/manufacturing practices and the locus of the error term across DAC codes.

Comment: @VidhyaPrasad: That I don't know.  It may be educational to work out what happens if there's a linear increase or decrease in resistance across an R-2R ladder -- from my long-ago time working with imaging chips, process defects tend to either come as bad areas on the chip, or as a gradient in parameters across the chip.  So you can think of the ways that you may lay out an R-2R ladder if you were a chip designer, and what would happen if there were a process gradient across that particular bit of real estate.